# Lotus Notes on Mac - "Error in loading DLL"

Tags: mac, lotus-notes

I'm running Lotus Notes 8.5.1 on a Mac 10.6.5.  Notes has, seemingly out of the blue, started displaying a message dialog box that simply says `Error in loading DLL` as I switch from one email to the next in my inbox. When I click OK, my email is displayed as expected so apart from the annoyance, Notes works fine. I don't get this dialog box when I'm in Offline mode.

I've googled it, but there doesn't seem to be any answers on this. Anyone familiar with this ultra unhelpful message?

Answer (score 0):

Are you the administrator or just an end user?  It sounds like maybe there is some lotus script running when you are switching between emails.  I'm not really familiar with the Mac version of Notes though.

You might try replacing the design on your mail file.  If you don't know how to do that, you'll want to contact your helpdesk.  Generally you do file->application-->replace design, then choose your primary mail server and select the mail template to use.